# Telerik Reporting Multiple y-axis in report

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-reporting, report-designer

Im using Telerik Standalone Report Designer to get a chart. Now, I have 2 column charts:

1. Sales amount by department
2. Number of transactions by department

And I want to combine both of them into one chart in this way:

Sales amount : left vertical axis
Number of transactions: right vertical axis
department: horizontal axis

May I know how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a second cartesian coordinate system to the first chart. This new coordinate system will share the X axis (department) with the already existing coordinate system, but will have a new Y axis that will display the number of transactions. Add a new column series that will display the number of transactions and select the second coordinate system in its "CoordinateSystem" property.
In order to move the Y axis on the right side of the X axis, you have to add two CrossAxisPosition entries in X axis' scale. The CrossAxisPositions defines where an axis will be crossed by other axes.
The process is described here: [How to: Add Secondary Axis](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/graphhowtoaddsecondaryaxis) and here: [How to: Create Graph with Column and Line Series](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/graphhowtocreategraphwithcolumnandlineseries)